trying to count business days from start date column and give a date 30 business days from start date column
Aloha, I am trying to calculate a running business day counter from [start date] column.
Also trying to calculate 30 business days from the same [start date] column.

calculated fields are getting updated only on item/file change or creation, meaning if you want to display dynamically changed value (every day diferent number) the calculated fields is a no go - Power Automate is or Custom JSON Column formatting. If you want to display static value (Start-date + 30 days) then you can use formula bellow.

=[start date]+[daysToAddColumn]+ROUNDDOWN([daysToAddColumn]/5,0)*2+IF(WEEKDAY([start date])+MOD([daysToAddColumn],5)>=7,2,0)-ROUNDDOWN(WEEKDAY([start date])/7,0)+IF(AND(MOD([daysToAddColumn],5)=0,WEEKDAY([start date])=1),-2,0)+IF(AND(MOD([daysToAddColumn],5)=0,WEEKDAY([start date])=7),-2,0) - calculating bussiness days, using column [daysToAddColumn] that can be raplaced with "30" in your case
